# UIAlertView showing up on Simulator, but not device

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have `UIAlertView` working as expected in simulator, and earlier in my App's development it worked well on the device, but as of now it doesn't show up.  I am however certain the code is running.  Help would be greatly appreciated.

`MacroEditViewController.h`:

```
@interface MacroEditViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

`MacoEditViewController.m`:

```
- (IBAction)saveDatabase:(UIButton *)sender 
{
            [self alertStatusWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Are you sure you want to override %@ for %@? This cannot be undone (But you can Reset All Overrides on Macros screen).", macroMeal[1], macroMeal[0]] :@"Update Macros"];
}

- (void) alertStatus:(NSString *)msg :(NSString *)title
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                        message:msg
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
    [alertView show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        [self saveUpdatesToDatabase];
    }

}
```

Comment: this is such a bad method name `- (void) alertStatus:(NSString *)msg :(NSString *)title;` needs renaming to `- (void)alertStatusWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message;`

Comment: @user3406093 - You can put UIAlertView code directly into saveDatabase: method - for your question remove [] use @"" for msg

Comment: @bhavyakothari I'm assuming this is a convenience method to allow them to just pass the title and message and the rest is the same.

Comment: I would really recommend reading https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF

Comment: @Popeye - But sometimes customizing,what is already convenient? generates minor mistakes which are hard to debug at first glance. Its better to stick to native style.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with convenience methods, I do this myself (Though I keep with naming convention) so I would have something like, `- (void)errorAlertWithMessage:(NSString *)message;` or `- (void)warningAlertWithMessage:(NSString *)message;` (these are just examples I don't actually have methods named this)

Comment: I fully understand the method name, etc could be improved.  The question I have per my post was why it would show on simulator but not device.  thanks.

Comment: This will now throw an unrecognized selector.

Comment: It should now be `[self alertStatus:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Are you sure you want to override %@ for %@? This cannot be undone (But you can Reset All Overrides on Macros screen).", macroMeal[1], macroMeal[0]] :@"Update Macros"];` if you have changed your code.

Comment: Have you put a break point in your alertStatus:: method to see that it's executing?

Comment: @CW0007007 (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex does not get called as the AlertView does not show giving the opportunity to click a button.  Up to that point, it runs well.

Comment: Does it run into the alertStatus method ?

Comment: I turned my phone off and on, and it fixed the issue. Very strange!

Answer (score 0):

Why did you call your function like this

```
[self alertStatus:[@"Are you sure you want to override?"] :@"Update Macros"];
```

Call it like this

```
[self alertStatus:@"Are you sure you want to override?" :@"Update Macros"];
```

without the square brackets, it may be the problem

Comment: That whole method needs renaming. It is not a descriptive method at all, goes against naming convention.

Comment: That was a typo on right square bracket after ?"].  I have edited, thanks.

Comment: @user3406093 it is still wrong, you need to remove the second `[` bracket.

Comment: Updated.  I put my actual code for that in, I had simplified for the post originally.

Comment: Never simply for the post we can't give a correct and accurate response to your problem otherwise and if we get any sense at all that you haven't supplied correct code to the problem we will just vote to close it.

Answer (score -2):

create a CIAlert.h

```
void CIAlert(NSString* title, NSString* alert);
void CIError(NSString* error);
```

and in CIAlert.m

```
#import "CIAlert.h"

void CIAlert(NSString* title, NSString* alert) {
UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:alert delegate:nil
                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
}

void CIError(NSString* error) {
  CIAlert(@"Error", error);
}
```

import the class CIAlert.h and call it just like this...

```
CIAlert(@"Title", @"Enter your message");
```

Comment: Why do it general `C` style over `objective-c` style? Do you not think this may cause a little confusion with someone who is new? (Just an assumption there based on the code they have provided) Also what does CI stand for?